# How to Validate a Laravel Form Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to validate a Laravel form via jQuery/Ajax. I have two form fields: 'email' and 'contact.' If anyone types in email and it's already registered then it will show "Email id already registered". And same like in contact. I have done it in PHP. However, it's not working in the view.

**register.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" id="Frm_sign" name="Frm_sign">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <label for="arrival">Contact No*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required digits" id="contact" name="contact"
               value="{{ old('contact') }}" placeholder="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <label for="arrival">Email id*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm email required" id="email" name="email"
               value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 pull-right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- form validation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
// - validation
        if ($('#Frm_sign').length > 0) {
            $('#Frm_sign').validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        remote: {
                            url: "{{url("varifyemail")}}",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {
                                action: function () {
                                    return "1";
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    contact: {
                        maxlength: 10,
                        minlength: 10,
                        remote: {
                            url: "{{url("varifycontact")}}",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {
                                action: function () {
                                    return "2";
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    password: {
                        equalTo: "#repass"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        remote: "Email id already registred"
                    },
                    contact: {
                        remote: "Mobile number already registred",
                        maxlength: "Please enter valid mobile number",
                        minlength: "Please enter valid mobile number"
                    },
                    password: {
                        equalTo: "Password is not equal"
                    }
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {

                    form.submit();
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parent());
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

In Ajax, there is password also but it's working, so I didn't write the password field here.

**Route**

```
Route::get('varifyemail','Auth\RegisterController@varifyemail');
Route::get('varifycontact','Auth\RegisterController@varifycontact');
```

**RegisterController**

```
public function varifyemail(Request $request)
{
    $email1 = User::where('email', $request->email)->get();
    if($email1->email > 0)
    {
        echo json_encode(false);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
}

public function varifycontact(Request $request)
{
    $contact1 = User::where('contact', $request->contact)->get();
    if($contact1->contact > 0)
    {
        echo json_encode(false);
    } else { 
        echo json_encode(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what "is not working" ? Did the jQuery plugin send the validation request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rules: {
    email: {
        remote: {
            url: "{{url("varifyemail")}}",
            type: "get",
            data: {
/*email was the action and it will be sent as request key name*/  
            email: function() {
                    return $( "#email" ).val(); //your email field
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't give any value and wrong action key name to your `varifyemail` request.

And Note in this case **better use `POST` instead of`GET`**

An example taken from the docs: [jQuery Validation Remote Metode](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Also overwrite your contact code

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I used POST instead of GET. But error got (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php line 251

Comment: Even I replace ROUTE::GET in both route

Comment: `Route::post` -> for post request
`Route::get` -> for get request

 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php happen because you send a wrong request.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just post the form with ajax and get the result from the php server. Since your validation is already working you'll just have to check if the response returned has an error or not. If there is an error you can output it to the screen (by for example looping over all the errors in the response).

The code would look similar to this:

```
$.ajax(method: "POST",
    url: "/your/endpoint",
    data: { email: "theemail", contact: "thecontact" }
})
 .done(function(res) { console.log('Success ' + res); })
 .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { console.log('Validation failed ' + textStatus); });
```